Error trying to load variables into registers and calling functions
I'm trying to understand functions and loops by building some. In the code below I'm simply trying to print hello world multiple times using a loop:
.global _start
_start:
    beq loop
        beq exit
loop:
    cmp x0, #0

    beq print

    sub x0, x0, #0
    beq exit

print: 
    mov x0, #0
    adrp x1, msg
    mov x2, #13
    mov x16, #4
    svc #0x80

    beq exit

exit:
    mov x0,#0
    mov x16, #1
    svc #0x80

.data
    msg: .ascii "Hello World!\n"

The problem is I'm getting an error when I run the code:
error: ADR/ADRP relocations must be GOT relative

and
error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!

I've also tried replacing the line:
adrp x1, msg

with
adrp x1, helloworld@page
add x1, x1, helloworld@pageoff

but then I get the error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "helloworld", referenced from:
      _start in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

When I run the print function code independently it prints hello world, but when I put it in the loop I get the errors mentioned above.
Just FYI I'm compiling the code with the following commands:
cc -c main.asm -o main.o
ld -o HelloWorld main.o -e _start
./HelloWorld


"Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:  helloworld" maybe because your string is actually called msg?

Please specify the OS you are using.

I am using MacOS

I tried Jester's suggestion and it compiles successfully, but only prints "hello world" once. How would I make it loop over to print it multiple times?

The two beq statements at the front make no sense. Similarly the beq exit just before the exit: makes no sense, sounds like you wanted b loop.

Suggest writing small loops and seeing what a compiler (godbolt.org) does with that.  To see good output from the compiler, turn on optimization, and, give it a small function that cannot be reduced to the empty function.

@ErikEidt: ARM64 GCC and clang on Godbolt target Linux.  To get macOS output, I think use clang with -target arm64-apple-darwin.  And yes, I think Linux vs. macOS actually does matter for AArch64 code that wants to get a label address into a register. (How to load data by label on Apple Silicon (ARM64)?)
